# JQuery Datepicker - displaying date in several fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

I'm having a list with several activities, and I want the jQuery Datepicker to display the date in a field in each row. 
At the moment I'm able to display the date in the first row, but it seem like it only will display in one field with id="date" at a time.
The field in each row look like this:

```
<td><input id="date" name="date" /></td>
```

So, what I'm wondering: Is there a way I can display the date in every input field with id="date"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ids` must be unique on a page. Use a class instead to identify the elements.

The reason is that browsers maintain a fast-lookup dictionary of id value vs element and there is only one entry per value available in a dictionary.

To use a class

```
<td><input class="date" name="date" /></td>
```

and target with `$(".date").datepicker();` instead of `$('#date').datepicker()`

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/D4AGz/485/

Answer (score 1):

Following what @TrueBlueAussie said, you can do :

```
$( ".your_class" ).each(function() { //You access all your elements with the class "your_class"
  //Do STG, you can access the current element with $(this)
});
```

Comment: You typically do not use `each` with jQuery unless the specific instances are actually needed. Most plugins will work fine with a selector result returning a collection.

Comment: I mean, it's one of the possibilities

Comment: Sure, but do not encourage `each` in jQuery unless specifically needed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, taking your list as example

```
<ul id="listDisp">
    <li>
        Activity 1<input type="text" id="datePicker1"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        Activity 2<input type="text" id="datePicker2"/>
    </li>
    <li>
        Activity 3<input type="text" id="datePicker3"/>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

and your js would be

```
$("#listDisp").find('input').datepicker();
```

OR

```
$("#listDisp input").datepicker();
```

Here is **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/06x34mt1/1/)**